# single node hadoop installation on ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: hadoop

I installed java and hadoop, but when I run the command for namenode formatting and `start-all.sh`, I get the following error:

```
:~$ hadoop namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

Comment: You are missing quite much information. What Hadoop version? How many nodes? What kind of cluster setup? Why do you say that the error comes in `start-all.sh` if it comes in `hadoop namenode -format` ? Formatting is done before starting the cluster, so it's pointless to try starting the cluster if the namenode formatting fails.